# Do we have onComplete and onAbort callback using <router-link> like router.push(location, onComplete?, onAbort?)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

As we know we have `onComplete` and `onAbort` optional callback as 2nd and 3rd argument in `router.push` method.

```
router.push(location, onComplete?, onAbort?)
```

These callbacks will be called when the navigation either successfully completed, or aborted.

Do we have `onComplete` and `onAbort` callback  using `<router-link>` ?

Comment: From [looking at the component definition](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/components/link.js), it does not appear so. The event handler for the component calls `router.push(location)` and does not specify  `onComplete` or `onAbort` handlers. So I'm thinking there's not even an unofficial way to do this. Might be a good feature request.

Comment: @thanksd Although there are no similar events in `router-link` component, I think one can simulate similar behaviour with the navigation guards. See my answer and correct me please, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can add **beforeRouteEnter()** for called compenent. Try "Fetching Before Navigation" on [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html) documentation.